# When I wake my computer from sleep mode, after a few seconds the wifi disconnects for about 5 minutes before reconnecting

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm not an expert on the technical side of computers so please bear with me.

I recently purchased a new HP laptop (model 15-dy1018ca). I have noticed that when it goes to sleep for longer than an hour, when I wake it up it connects to my saved network very briefly. If I'm quick enough I can load a website or two. But after a few seconds, it disconnects from the internet. My network settings say "connected, no internet". The worst part is that somehow every other device that is connected to my network gets disconnected from the internet at the same time (cell phones, tablets, game systems, TV). If I wait about 5 minutes everything resolves itself, the laptop (and everything else) reconnects automatically. I'm not sure how they would be related, but it happens too often to be a coincidence. The network doesn't behave this way when other devices connect. I haven't tried connecting my laptop to a different network since I'm working from home right now. It also doesn't seem to happen if the computer only goes to sleep for a short time.

I've tried searching for a solution but haven't been able to find anything that fits my issue exactly. I have tried disabling the network adapter option that "allows the computer to turn off this device to save power" but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

EDIT: My laptop is running Windows 10. My wireless router was provided to me by my service provider, but there's no model number or brand name anywhere on it. I wouldn't know how to change anything about the router so I assume it's the same as it was when I got several months ago.

Comment: If all the devices disconnect at the same time, the common denominator is probably the router. Check for a firmware update (or let us know its model). Do you reboot the router frequently, or like never?

Comment: By any chance, do you have custom third party firmware on your router like DD WRT or Open WRT? If you have mobile Internet and facility to create mobile hotspot, for testing purposes, switch off your router and hook all your devices like Tablet and that laptop to your mobile hotspot. Does the issue repeat after your laptop wakes up from sleep now? Also check router logs if they can provide any meaningful information when it happens.

Comment: @harrymc When the internet connection first dropped, before i suspected the cause, I did reboot the router. I haven't since because everything reconnects automatically in about the same amount of time as if I reconnected the router. But I never had this issue with my old laptop.

Comment: @patkim I'm not sure how I would check the router logs or what I'd be looking for.

Comment: You may like to Edit your question and provide bit more details like Operating System on your Laptop. The router make/model number. Does your router use default stock firmware or any third-party custom firmware like DD-WRT / Open WRT and the version of firmware?  After Internet drops, are you able to access the router’s default admin page from your laptop? If Windows 10, just give a try with Network Reset. Search for Network Reset in Windows 10 Search and proceed with the Network reset. You will have to restart you PC and manually connect to your WiFi network once thereafter.

Comment: @patkim I edited my post as suggested, but I don't have much more info than originally given. I also followed your advice about network reset. It doesn't seem to fixed the problem, but now my laptop shows two works: one with the original name and another "original name 2". I can't connect via laptop to the original, although all my other devices can. When my laptop does eventually reconnect to the internet automatically it connects to the new one.

Comment: Check if Windows 10 is up-to-date. If not update the same. Check HP website for any latest device drivers and update them. Also in case there's an option to Rollback Driver for WiFi adapter under Device Manager, do try that first before updating as well. Check if there's any BIOS update for your laptop and update the same. If issue persists, report to your ISP and insist for a new Router with latest firmware. Did you try connecting your laptop to your mobile internet hotspot, just in case you have that facility on your phone and Internet on mobile?